# How can you do a Lollipop Shared Element Transition between Drawer and Fragment?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop

I want to do a Lollipop shared element transition between a navigation drawer (embedded in parent activity) and a fragment. Specifically, the top of the drawer has a profile picture and if the user clicks on it, I want the the profile image from the top of the drawer to transform to the top of the profile fragment that launches. This drawer is used to switch between a few of fragments.

I've seen how to do Activity to Activity transitions, and Fragment to Fragment transitions, but not Activity to Fragment transitions.

Basically I'm looking for advice or a sample of how to take a component from the drawer in my activity and have it transition to a fragment when the fragment is added or shown.

Has anyone done this or know how to do this?

Comment: maybe you could get a clue from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386397/shared-element-transitions-between-views-not-activities-or-fragments

Comment: I have come across the same issue any luck solving it?

Comment: @pkramaric I haven't had time to explore yet, but it sounds like a scene/view transition (as detailed in linked reference from sorianiv) may work from a view in the navigation drawer to a view in the fragment.

Comment: @jt-gilkeson Any luck solving this?