# Shared Element Transition + Content Transition

Tags: android, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to achieve something real similar to the gif that can be seen in the following link:

[Shared Element Transitions Between Views (not Activities or Fragments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386397/shared-element-transitions-between-views-not-activities-or-fragments)

The only difference between that the `transition` needs to take place when there is an click event on a `recyclerview` item which is within an `fragment` (The fragment resides within an `activity`). The `onClick` then propogates to an `activity` which in turn hosts the actual `fragment` consisting of the details.

How can we go about achieving such animation?

For reference this is what my details xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dip">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                android:layout_margin="10dip"
                android:id="@+id/detailsCardTitleNameTextView"
            />

            <include layout="@layout/divider_details"/>

            <TextView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text = "@string/director_name"
                android:layout_margin="10dip"
                android:id="@+id/detailsCardDirectorTextView"
            />



            <TextView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_margin="10dip"
                android:text="@string/released_date"
                android:id="@+id/detailsCardReleasedTextView"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

        android:id="@+id/card_view5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dip">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                android:layout_margin="10dip"
                android:text="@string/writers_title"
                android:id="@+id/detailsCardWriterTitleTextView"
            />

            <include layout="@layout/divider_details"/>

            <TextView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_margin="10dip"
                android:id="@+id/detailsCardWritersTextView"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

        android:id="@+id/card_view2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dip">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <TextView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                android:text="@string/plot_title"
                android:layout_margin="10dip"
                android:id="@+id/detailsCardPlotTitleTextView"
            />

            <include layout="@layout/divider_details"/>

            <TextView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_margin="10dip"
                android:id="@+id/detailsCardPlotTextView"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

        android:id="@+id/card_view3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dip">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                android:layout_margin="10dip"
                android:text="@string/imdb_rating"
                android:id="@+id/imdbRatingTitleTextView"
            />

            <include layout="@layout/divider_details"/>

            <TextView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_margin="10dip"
                android:id="@+id/imdbRatingTextView"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas, tips much appreciated.
Thanks!