# Shared animation transition when moving view from one container View Group to another

Tags: android, animation, transition, shared-element-transition

I have a complex layout [Image of Views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKsvG.png) and in my code
I do

```
val viewtoMove = innerContainer.getChildAt(0)
innerContainer.removeView(viewtoMove)
FrameLayout2.addView(viewtoMove, 0)
```

I am struggling to set up Shared animation with scene transition between these.
I am moving a view from one container to other , so its not within a same parent.
The closest common parent is Parent container.

How can I set up transition to do change bounds .

I refered [Shared Element Transitions Between Views (not Activities or Fragments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386397/shared-element-transitions-between-views-not-activities-or-fragments) but I am missing not able to traslate it into mysolution.

I am not sure how to create the end Scene and how would system understand starting scene.

I read the document and found that ChangeTransform, handles view changes of different containers , but I am not sure how to set it up in code.